# IBM watson IoT platform-Hex data

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-iot, lorawan

My question is about connecting loriot network server to the IBM Watson IoT Platform.
I have managed to connect loriot backend with the Watson IoT Platform  and see some data coming through. However, the data are in a hexadecimal format. Any idea on how I can convert this hex data to be human readable?

Comment: In this recipe ( https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/connecting-your-device-with-ibm-watson-iot-using-a-thingpark-lorawan-network/ ) they used a bridge decoder to do the conversion. You may also want to check for any lora nodes in node-red that may be able to help with conversion.

Comment: this video  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H18pVF8qIaY showing how to configure LoRa  with multitech conduit may be helpful to you

Answer (score 0):

If the data coming through to the Watson IoT Platform is in JSON format, but contains properties whose values are in hex, you can use the **Data Management** capabilities to convert the data in these events to Device State.  The expression language used in the property mapping expressions includes an **$unpack** function that can be used to convert strings and hex octets to numeric values.  When used in conjunction with the **$substring** function, you can extract specific strings from a large hex value and convert it to a number.

As an example, say you had the following inbound event:

```
{
  "propertyA": "valueA",
  "propertyB": "valueB",
  "data": "3b45940201000000010e4601"
}
```

... you could map values to properties on the device state using mapping expressions similar to the following:

```
$unpack($substring($event.data, 0, 8),  "l32f")
$unpack($substring($event.data, 8, 2),  "l8")
$unpack($substring($event.data, 10, 8), "l32")
```

The corresponding output of the three expressions above is:

```
2.1786381830505485E-37
1
16777216
```

The **Data Management** capabilities are documented here:

https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/IoT/GA_information_management/ga_im_device_twin.html#device_twins